# result with "like" in query using doctrine 2

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my news web page I would like to have a related news using "keywords" quoted in principal news and im using this query :

```
   public function RelatedNews($limit,$offset=0,$keywords)

  {    
     $q = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
         $q->select('n.title,n.shortContent,n.longContent,n.keywords')
           ->from('MyAppMyBundle:News', 'n')
            ->where($q->expr()->like('n.keywords', $q->expr()->literal('%' . $keywords . '%')))
              ->setFirstResult( $offset )
              ->setMaxResults( $limit );  

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();

  }
```

The query is correct but just when it find one keyword and I have a wrong result when I put a list of words

In my table "News" I have a row "keywords" and I store my keywords like that  :

```
word 1 , word 2 , word 3 ...
```

so I hope to have result when the query find a word in a list of words...

Comment: Provide more details, i don't really understand what's you issue here

Comment: @AdrienBrault ok I find a solution in answer of redbirdo,tnks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE %value% will match any string containing the substring 'value'.

Therefore the query in the question will only result in a match for multiple keywords if the string of keywords entered happens to be a substring of the keywords on one of the news items.

For example, if you have a news item with keywords = "cycling,france,wiggins" then you will get a match if you enter "cycling,france" or "france,wiggins" but not "cycling,wiggins" or even "cycling, france" or "cycling france".

If you alter the value of the $keywords string passed in to separate the keywords with the % wildcard char then you should get the matches you are looking for.

For example if you convert "cycling, wiggins" to "%cycling%wiggins%" then it will match "cycling,france,wiggins".

However, note that using this LIKE approach a query of "fran, gin" would also match "cycling,france,wiggins". To match whole keywords a better approach is to store your keywords individually on a separate table and use a different sort of query.